# Fancy way to read a file in C++ : strange performance issue

Tags: c++, performance, file, iterator

The usual way to read a file in C++ is this one:

```
std::ifstream file("file.txt", std::ios::binary | std::ios::ate);
std::vector<char> data(file.tellg());
file.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
file.read(data.data(), data.size());
```

Reading a 1.6 MB file is almost instant.

But recently, I discovered [std::istream_iterator](http://cplusplus.com/reference/std/iterator/istream_iterator/) and wanted to try it in order to code a beautiful one-line way to read the content of a file. Like this:

```
std::vector<char> data(std::istream_iterator<char>(std::ifstream("file.txt", std::ios::binary)), std::istream_iterator<char>());
```

The code is nice, but **very** slow. It takes about 2/3 seconds to read the same 1.6 MB file. I understand that it may not be the best way to read a file, but why is it **so** slow?

Reading a file in a classical way goes like this (I'm talking only about the read function):

- the istream contains a [filebuf](http://cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/filebuf/) which contains a block of data from the file
- the read function calls [sgetn](http://cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/streambuf/sgetn/) from the filebuf, which copies the chars one by one (no memcpy) from the inside buffer to "data"'s buffer
- when the data inside of the filebuf is entirely read, the filebuf reads the next block from the file

When you read a file using istream_iterator, it goes like this:

- the vector calls *iterator to get the next char (this simply reads a variable), adds it to the end and increases its own size
- if the vector's allocated space is full (which happens not so often), a relocation is performed
- then it calls ++iterator which reads the next char from the stream (operator >> with a char parameter, which certainly just calls the filebuf's sbumpc function)
- finally it compares the iterator with the end iterator, which is done by comparing two pointers

I must admit that the second way is not very efficient, but it's at least 200 times slower than the first way, how is that possible?

I thought that the performance killer was the relocations or the insert, but I tried creating an entire vector and calling std::copy, and it's just as slow.

```
// also very slow:
std::vector<char> data2(1730608);
std::copy(std::istream_iterator<char>(std::ifstream("file.txt", std::ios::binary)), std::istream_iterator<char>(), data2.begin());
```

Comment: "I thought that the performance killer was the relocations or the insert" - this is why you need to rely on profiling.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should compare apple-to-apple.

Your first code read **unformatted** binary data because you use the function member "read". And not because you use std::ios_binary by the way, see http://stdcxx.apache.org/doc/stdlibug/30-4.html for more explication, but in short : "The effect of the binary open mode is frequently misunderstood. It does not put the inserters and extractors into a binary mode, and hence suppress the formatting they usually perform. Binary input and output is done solely by basic_istream<>::read() and basic_ostream<>::write()"

So your second code with istream_iterator read **formatted** text. It's way slower.

If you want to read unformatted binary data, use istreambuf_iterator :

```
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

std::ifstream file( "file.txt", std::ios::binary);
std::vector<char> buffer((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(file)),
                          std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
```

On my platform (VS2008), istream_iterator is about x100 slower than read(). istreambuf_iterator performs better, but still x10 slower than read().

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think about locale, width to extract, etc.

Comment: But how can the processing of the data in memory be 100 times slower than the file I/O?

Answer (score 3):

Only profiling will tell you why exactly.  My guess would be that what you are seeing is just the overhead of all of the extra function calls associated with the second method.  Instead of a single call to bring in all the data, you are doing 1.6M calls*... or something along those lines.

* Many of them are virtual which means two CPU cycles per call. (Tks Zan)

Comment: Yeah, and those calls are indirect virtuals. Those suck.

Comment: Profiling tells me that a lot of functions consume between 3 and 5 % of the total each, no function comes out at the top ; I mark you as accepted answer

Answer (score 1):

The iterator approach reads the file one character at a time, while the file.read does it in a single hit.

If the operating system/file handlers know you want to read a large amount of data, there's lots of optimizations that can be done - maybe reading the whole file on a single revolution of the disk spindle, not copying data from OS buffers to application buffers.

When you do byte-by-byte transfers, the OS has no clue what you're really wanting to do, so cannot perform such optimizations.

Comment: The filebuf object inside of fstream reads the file block-by-block. Anyway it's the same way to read the file in both cases, it's just copying from filebuf to vector<char> that is slow